# How can I send an automated email from a Google sheet updated by Squarespace?

Tags: google-apps-script, squarespace

I have a form run from SquareSpace that inputs the customer data to a Google Sheet. I'm currently running the below script, but the trigger OnFormSubmit doesn't work. I have to go in and manually run the script.

```
function FormConfirmationEmail() {

  var sheetname = "Request Financial Assistance"
  var columnnumber = 6

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetname);

  if (sheet.getRange(sheet.getMaxRows(),1).getValue() != "") {
     var lastrow = sheet.getMaxRows()    
  } else {
     var count = 0
     for (var i = 0; i < sheet.getMaxRows(); i++) {
        if (sheet.getRange(sheet.getMaxRows()-i,1).getValue() != "") {
        var lastrow = sheet.getMaxRows()-i
        break;
        }  
     }
  }

  var email = sheet.getRange(lastrow,columnnumber).getValue();  
  var emailPattern = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|aero|asia|biz|com|coop|edu|gov|info|int|jobs|mil|mobi|name|museum|name|net|org|pro|tel|travel)\b/;
  var validEmailAddress = emailPattern.test(email); 

  if (validEmailAddress == true) {
    var message = "<HTML><BODY>"
     + "<P>This is an automated form completion email.  Thanks for submitting!"
     + "</HTML></BODY>";      
     MailApp.sendEmail(email, "Form Completion Email", "", {htmlBody: message});      

     sheet.getRange(lastrow,13,1,1).setValue("Email Sent");
      }  else{
     sheet.getRange(lastrow,13,1,1).setValue("Email not Sent - Invalid Email Address submitted");
  }
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using a Google form? How is square space implied in this question?  Did you set the trigger manually from the resource menu?

Comment: No, I'm not using a Google form. It is generated from SquareSpace, but the data is linked to a Google Sheet, so it populates the same way a Google Form would do. And yes --- I set the trigger manually from the resource menu.

Comment: I think the triggers 'see' only Google forms... although I never tried. in that case the best you could do is using a timer that looks at the lastRow value in the sheet and triggers when a new row is added. Or (that could work too) use an onChange handler and see if it triggers on the new row added by the form. Keep us up to date with this please. thx

Comment: @AubreyMurray did you ever find a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the trigger in the Google sheet that is collecting the responses and the Form Submit trigger should work.

```
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("FormConfirmationEmail")
  .forSpreadsheet(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet())
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
```

Also, instead of using getMaxRow(), you can use the e parameter that is passed to the FormSubmit function to parse and email the user submitted data.

See: [Get Google Forms Data in Email](http://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884/)

Comment: Thanks, Amit. Unfortunately, I am EXTREMELY new to scripts and need a little more direction. Where do I paste that code, and does it need to have anything else included?